# Unauthenticated error after deploy laravel/react

Tags: reactjs, laravel, authentication, deployment

I have a problem after deploy laravel react application with Scalingo

I'm connected on the application. I have xsrf token and session cookie.

I deploy and then i have "unauthenticated" error if i refresh or change page.
I still have my xsrf token and session in cookies.

Someone can help me please ?

Comment: Do you regenerate the app key at each deploy? That will break any cookies or token encrypted using that key as salt.

Comment: i just have this in my composer.json for the key but it's not supposed to run during deployment, right ? 

    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }

Answer (score 0):

I changed my SESSION_DRIVER from 'file' to 'cookie' and that work